# What data type can be able to write null values into Apache IoTDB Version 1.0?

Tags: null, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I need to write some `null` values into Apache IoTDB Version 1.0. I wanto to know does this version supports writing `null` values? Or what data type can support this execution of writing `null` values into the database?

Answer (score 0):

If your data written into Apache IoTDB is in `string` type, then you can directly write `null` values and they will be written into IoTDB. If data is not in `string` type, then you may need to change this data type before successfully writing `null` values in IoTDB.